# If I pass some string by reference to a Class Constructor then why is the address of the string(class member) different from the actual string

Tags: c++

I don't understand, If I pass a string by ref. to a function then the address of actual string passed will be same as that of formal string in this function. Any changes to either will impact on either of the two. But it is not same for passing string by ref. to a class ctor. Why is that? Although I do understand, different objects must have different addresses.

```
Class Abc
{
  private:
    std::string s;
  public:
    Abc(std::string str)
    : s(str)
    {}
};

void fun(std::string& str)
{  str [0]='i';}  // changes content in st

int main()
{
    std::string st = "hello";
    Abc obj(st);

    //if we change st shouldn't it change s in obj 
    st[0] = 'j';

    fun(st);
}
```

Comment: Because you aren't passing it by reference to the class. Look at your constructor, it is accepting a string, not a reference to a string.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to apply the fixes provided by the answers. Doing so invalidates those answers making them meaningless. Leave the question with the initial error so that future readers can benefit from the full context of the question.

Comment: If you remove the indirections through a class and a function, that is the same as `int main() { std::string st = "hello"; std::string s(st); st[0] = 'j'; st[0] = 'i';}`

Answer (score 3):

Your member variable `std::string s;` is not a reference, it's a plain string. So when you initialize it it gets constructed by copying the string you initialize it with.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying the string by value in the constructor.

This is how you would store the reference:

```cpp
class Abc{
    std::string& str;
  public:
    Abc(std::string& s): str(s){}
};

void foo(){
    std::string str;
    Abc abc(str);
    str = ”Hello World”;
     /// abc.str is now also hello world 
}
```

But now, beware about lifetimes!
By passing the object by reference to the object in the constructor, the lifetime is not extended, meaning when str goes out of scope, abc.str points to invalid memory -> undefined behavior.

C++, unlike other languages such as python is a value-based language as in that assignments copy by default unless you do extra tricks like `move`, taking the address or taking a reference (which is a similar thing to taking the address).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you're not passing the string as a reference to the constructor.

```
Abc(std::string str)
```

should be

```
Abc(std::string& str)
```

If you want the value change of the original string to reflect into the member variable in class(or the other way around). Then you need to make member variable as reference. Your class should look like

```
Class Abc
{
 private:
     std::string& s;
 public:
      Abc(std::string& str)
         : s(str)
      {}
 };
```